# Convert empty cells in a data table to 0

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a data table that has 1 column having few cells having null value. How can I convert them to 0 ?

I bind this data table to a data grid view and cells are  empty in case of null in the data table.I need to have 0 displayed in the datagridview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set the property of the DataGridViewTextBox column .Seems to be working as expected.

```
amountColumn.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = "0";
```

Answer (score 6):

Edit your cell template and set the NullValue to 0

Comment: but it a datagrid view in Winform. So I dont think this will work

Comment: Go to columns editor, select the column, click the DefaultCellTemplate property and set the value in the template property editor. A cell template is not an asp.net thing

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, I'd clear this up before binding to the datagrid.  I'd execute a for loop and just change all the DBNull values to 0.  Its quick, easy, understandable code.  This has the benefit of actually changing the *data* to 0, instead of changing how it is *viewed* to 0, as others have suggested by making tweaks to the dataGrid.  Either strategy has merits, just depends on what you want to do.

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow row = dataTable.Rows[i];

    if (row["ColumnA"] == DBNull.Value)
    {
        row["ColumnA"] = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this works for all rows and columns with null or empty values

```
For i As Integer = 0 To output.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        Dim row As DataRow = output.Tables(0).Rows(i)

        For j As Integer = 0 To output.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
            If row(j) Is DBNull.Value Then
                row(j) = 0
            End If
            If row(j).ToString.Length = 0 Then
                row(j) = 0
            End If
        Next

    Next
```

C#

```
for (int i = 0; i <= output.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    DataRow row = output.Tables[0].Rows[i];
    for (int j = 0; j <= output.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(row[j], DBNull.Value))
        {
            row[j] = 0;
        }
        if (row[j].ToString().Length == 0)
        {
            row[j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you fetch data to display from database then you might bind null to 0 using following syntax:

```
SELECT ISNULL(ColumnName, 0)
FROM TableName;
```

Comment: but Iam not fetching the data from database. Iam reading an excel file.Empty cells in the excel becomes null in the data table and so when I bind it to the data grid view, it cell is empty

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                            {
                                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows[i][j].ToString()))
                                {

                                    dt.Rows[i][j] = "0";
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: if the column is type of int you are going to get an exception for the `ToString()`